# ghc fails to compile anything and gives seemingly unrelated error message

Tags: haskell, ghc

`ghc —-make -dynamic project-name` spits out this error message:

```
Loaded package environment from /home/[username]/.ghc/x86_64-linux-8.10.1/environments/default
<command line>: cannot satisfy -package-id brick-0.55-36a4fd555898e5099631028e3dcfc1ab430aba6c8e86de8297433f9de5b18548:
    brick-0.55-36a4fd555898e5099631028e3dcfc1ab430aba6c8e86de8297433f9de5b18548 is unusable due to missing dependencies:
      config-ini-0.2.4.0-d2e694efd4eafb3c19f54d5364bddfeaef83ebee43b5e5882a7f42aa35485336 dlist-0.8.0.8-AISWFA9hhNRJt3GfCAStS5 text-zipper-0.10.1-02b81a026fbd2433d829cef38af07e088bb56eda2a88ad07845b65c3dc0b832b vector-0.12.1.2-CYdo0xBKGbnK8ZGEF4yFOM vty-5.30-4f3da73dbce9851125aecf0198ce599f03b003df7d866f1ff30cbe9673b5f07a
    (use -v for more information)
```

It does this for anything I try to compile, even though none of my projects use `brick`. I tried to fix this with `ghc-pkg unregister brick`, but this gives the error `ghc-pkg: cannot find package brick`. I do not remember trying to uninstall brick. Also, neither `vty` nor `text-zipper` appear in `cabal —-list-installed` or `ghc-pkg list`, even though I remember using cabal to install `brick` and `vty`.

Comment: `cabal install --lib` doesn't install packages in GHC's package database, it uses its own separate package database under Cabal control. Package environment files tell `ghc` and `ghci` where to find package databases. You can delete that `environments/default` environment file (it's a simple text file) and the problem should go away. If you want to compile a program that has external dependencies without creating a .cabal file, the best way is to create a *local* package environment as described here https://discourse.haskell.org/t/how-to-install-modules/1363/3?u=danidiaz

Comment: Wow, that worked. What a stupidly simple solution, thank you.